# keep javascript variables values obtained by id after refresh

Tags: javascript, html

i'm getting some html input values with javascript that i insert in a table , but those turned null when i refresh , how can i keep those value visible after refresh . I know i should set and get my cookies but i just don't how .
 here is my javascript code :

```
function myFunction(tableID) {
  var x = document.getElementById("name").value;
  var ad = document.getElementById("address").value;
  var nu = document.getElementById("tel").value;
  var pr = document.getElementById("product").value;
  var s = document.getElementById("size").value;
  var d = document.getElementById("date").value;
  var st = document.getElementById("statu").value;
  var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
  var rowCount = table.rows.length;
  var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);

  var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
  cell1.innerHTML = x;

  var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
  cell2.innerHTML = ad;

  var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
  cell3.innerHTML = nu;

  var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);
  cell4.innerHTML = pr;

  var cell5 = row.insertCell(4);
  cell5.innerHTML = s;

  var cell6 = row.insertCell(5);
  cell6.innerHTML = d;

  var cell7 = row.insertCell(6);
  cell7.innerHTML = st;
}
```

any help ?

THanks

Comment: You can use [___`localStorage`___](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)..

Comment: As Rayon said, you can use `LocalStorage` or if you need to be compliant with all browsers, you can look into using `Cookies`

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it would be to stick them in sessionStorage (which will be accessible across page refreshes).

To store them:

```
sessionStorage.setItem('foo', 'bar');
```

to get them:

```
sessionStorage.getItem('foo');
```

When your page is loaded, you can get them from the sessionStorage to repopulate your elements.

Comment: what if i have multiple rows . the functions adds rows on submit . how can i get the values in every row back ?

Comment: I believe values will be converted to a string, but if you set the value as an array of values, you can then retrieve it and turn back into an array by splitting on the comma.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/LocalStorage)

```
// before you leave your page , save all your variables here

window.onunload = function(){

  // save them one by one in to localStorage
  localStorage.setItem("x", x)
  ...
}
```

when you enter the page load from localStorage first :

```
// before all your code work.
window.onload = function (){

  // set value back one by one 
  document.getElementById("name").value = localStorage.getItem("x");
  ...
}
```

Comment: i can get the value in the form back but not those in the table . how can i keep the entries in the table . how can get back the previous number of rows and their entries?

Comment: You just need to save the count, the value and put it back like what you did on form. Isn't that similar work?